# How to pass value from application.properties in spring boot to class constructor? Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am using telegrambots lib and want to create bot class:

```
@Service
class MyBot : TelegramLongPollingBot(<TOKEN>) {
    ///
}
```

I am newbie in Spring and kotlin at all. I mostly copied code from tutorials, but for some reason all of them use deprecated way by creating function that returns private string recived by @Value instead passing this info in constructor.

I have tried a lot of options such as

```
@Service
class MyBot : TelegramLongPollingBot(@Value("\${telegram.botToken}") String botToken) {
    ///
}
```

```
class AppConfig {
    @Value("\${telegram.botToken}")
    lateinit var botToken: String
}

@Service
class MyBot : TelegramLongPollingBot(AppConfig.botToken) {
    ///
}
```

```
@Value("\${telegram.botName}")
lateinit var botToken: String

@Service
class MyBot : TelegramLongPollingBot(botToken) {
    ///
}
```

```
@Value("\${telegram.botName}")
var botToken: String = ""

@Service
class MyBot : TelegramLongPollingBot(botToken) {
    ///
}
```

Bot none of these work. Mostly it doesnt compile. So I want to know how can i pass token to constructor of expandable class